# How to build rpi 4 linux kernel,can't find target "bcm2711_defconfig"?

Tags: kernel

There is rpi linux kernel:

```
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
```

as

```
https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html
```

said,should use

```
cd linux
KERNEL=kernel7l
make bcm2711_defconfig
```

to build the kernel,but in the makefile I can't find the target bcm2711_defconfig

so what is the process of the rpi linux kernel build?Thanks!